# Documentação de um software desenvolvido

Tags: java, documentação, uml

O ficheiro deverá conter:

- Explicação da BD, junto do Modelo ER
- Explicação da Interface,
- Explicação dos ficheiros de propriedades
- Criação do Diagrama de caso de uso(ou outro do género que exemplifique todo o progresso do software desde o utilizador abrir até fechar)

Ultimo e mais importante penso eu

- Criação do Diagrama de classes

Eu sei que a criação do diagrama de classes devia de ser a primeira coisa quando iniciei o projeto mas não foi realizado.

**Perguntas**

1. Quanto aos tópicos que falei em cima estão certos? Devo remover/alterar/acrescentar algum?
2. Quanto ao diagrama de classes existe algum programa que faça o reverso de passar de classes(código Java) para a criação dos rectângulos UML, ou no caso de não existir algum bom exemplo para me poder orientar?

**IDE é o netbeans**

Comment: Para tua primeira pergunta, as respostas são demasiado baseadas em opiniões para o formato do StackOverflow. Para a sua segunda pergunta, creio que indicação de ferramentas seja fora de escopo (no stackoverflow em inglês pelo menos é off-topic).

Comment: Vou acompanhar pra ver outras opiniões quanto ao enquadramento da sua pergunta. Quanto a ferramentas, existe sim. Ex: http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/1801/netbeans-uml. Quanto a documentação, de modo geral (porque é super discutível) escreva só a documentação que alguém esteja interessado em ler agora (manual de instalação e manual de uso do sistema se não for muito intuitivo, por exemplo). Ou escreva tudo que você listou se estiverem pagando por isso :D

Comment: Acho uma questão bem discutível, sugiro levarmos ao meta